# How to install \documentclass{aa} on MacTex?

Tags: installing, document-classes

I need to convert a draft to the layout of the journal Astronomy & Astrophysics. My MacTex distribution doesn't recognise the document class, so I suppose I have to install it.

I downloaded the "A&A LaTeX macro package" [from their webpage](https://www.aanda.org/for-authors). The downloaded folder includes a bunch of files:

[image]

The content of the readme files can also be viewed online at [this link](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/readme.html).

I suppose what is left to do is to put all those files into the proper location. But where are these locations? I am on Max OS 10.15.3 and I have a fairly recently (Feb 2020) installed MacTex distribution. Cheers!

Comment: I suppose it does, thank you! I tried to simply put everything in the document folder, and it worked. I however get some errors when trying to typeset a minimal example. If I cannot figure them out, I might open a separate thread for that. Thanks again!

Comment: Try moving the .bst file from the bibtex folder into the same folder as the document and the .cls file. If that works there is a more general place to put the files to easily use them for multiple documents.